# Old SSIS in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, ssis

We are in a process of migrating our SQL Server 2005 to the 2012 version.

There's a significant number of SSIS (developedn in VS 2005) running on this server.

Will it be ok to just re-deploy these packages on the new SQL instance?

Or will I have to go through the Visual Studio upgrade process for each?

Any comments, advice appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the upgrade, for a variety of reasons.

In 2005, packages would have been stored in msdb.dbo.sysdtspackages90 From 2008 forward, that table was renamed to msdb.dbo.sysssispackages

Even if you deploy them into sysssispackages and kept a 2005 Integration Services Service installed, I don't think the 2005 dtexec would work with the 2008 version of the stored procs in msdb relative to SSIS work. The procs should be backwards compatible for the msdb SSIS "stuff" in 2012 as they poured all of their attention into the 2012 SSISDB catalog and the CLR methods there.

Depending on your Connection Managers, the SQL Server OLE DB connection strings changed from SQLNCLI01 to SQLNCLI1.0 (approximate)

The internals of how Data Flows works has also changed. The mechanism for signaling the end of rows changed between 2005 and 2008 so if you have any custom components, those will have to be reworked.

When you convert from 2005 to 2012, you can migrate to a Project Deployment model or the Package Deployment Model. As it seems you are looking for a minimum of change, stick with Package Deployment Model. The project deployment model will entail forgoing your Configurations in lieu of the fancy new Parameter methodology.